# Using go_router package in a flutter app with a statefulShellRoute, how to navigate to routes outside of the shell?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I have implemented go_router statefulShellRoute for bottomNavigationBar to have nested routes in a flutter app.

But I also have pages I want to be outside of the statefulShellRoute (outside bottom nav bar), i have these routes defined in GoRouter outside of the shell routes list but when I navigate to them using context.push(), as expected I can still see the Bottom Navigation Bar since it pushes the new screen onto the nested navigation stack.

If I use context.go(), even though I can reach the page and make the bottom nav bar disappear, I can't go back now since the previous route was replaced.

How can I push a route outside of the bottom navigation bar shell and still have the ability to come back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was searching for the same question before. Here is the answer for future searchers: you need to assign `parentNavigatorKey` for your route to be pushed over shell route. Example from go_router repo (pay attention to `_rootNavigatorKey`):

```
  final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    initialLocation: '/a',
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      /// Application shell
      ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
          return ScaffoldWithNavBar(child: child);
        },
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          /// The first screen to display in the bottom navigation bar.
          GoRoute(
            path: '/a',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ScreenA();
            },
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              // The details screen to display stacked on the inner Navigator.
              // This will cover screen A but not the application shell.
              GoRoute(
                path: 'details',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return const DetailsScreen(label: 'A');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),

          /// Displayed when the second item in the the bottom navigation bar is
          /// selected.
          GoRoute(
            path: '/b',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ScreenB();
            },
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              /// Same as "/a/details", but displayed on the root Navigator by
              /// specifying [parentNavigatorKey]. This will cover both screen B
              /// and the application shell.
              GoRoute(
                path: 'details',
                parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return const DetailsScreen(label: 'B');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**A perfect Example for this:**

*How it looks in the App:*
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/G8D2SSIWHfU

*Full Article:*
https://medium.com/flutter-community/integrating-bottom-navigation-with-go-router-in-flutter-c4ec388da16a

*Code gist link:*
https://gist.github.com/onatcipli/aed0372c987b4ae32311fe32bb4c1209